# HP ALM OTA-API: How to update a test in testlab knowing the id?

Tags: testing, ota, alm

I know the id of a test that is in a Testset and want to update your status, know how to do it using the API OTA?

**Edit:**
Thanks but current answer unfortunately doesn't work for me .
I put the example ( java) :

```java
ITestSetFactory sTestFactory = (itdc.testSetFactory()).queryInterface(ITestSetFactory.class);
ITDFilter filterF=sTestFactory.filter().queryInterface(ITDFilter.class);
filterF.filter("TC_TEST_ID","531729");
System.out.println(filterF.newList().count());
```

The error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com4j.ComException: 800403ea (Unknown error) : Failed to Get Test Set Value : .\invoke.cpp:517
    at com4j.Wrapper.invoke(Wrapper.java:166)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy13.newList(Unknown Source)
    at TestQC.main(TestQC.java:64)
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: You should provide some additional information like the language you use or what you have tried so far (some code and where it fails).

Comment: Sorry for the delay in the response . It is in java . Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because you use the TestSetFactory instead of the TSTestFactory. You should use `itdc.tsTestFactory()` because it is TSTest objects you want to manipulate (aka test instances), not TestSet objects. The simplest way is to get the TSTestFactory of your TDConnection object, and use a filter to get the TSTest object and then set its status. Example code in Ruby:

```
ts_test_factory = tdc.TSTestFactory
filter = ts_test_factory.Filter
filter["TC_TEST_ID"] = "123" # test id from test plan
found_test_instances = filter.NewList
test_instance = found_test_instances.Item(1) # be careful if the test occurs in many test sets
test_instance.Status = "Passed"
test_instance.Post
```